# Print from static content oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have region in oracle apex application page, which is static, Now I am trying to print the region with the built in print action (Dynamic Action) but I am not getting desired results. What is the best and simplest way to print this invoice in my desired way. Thank You.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you want it to look/behave, and how much you want to spend. You can play with CSS media queries

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/07/apex-printer-friendly-pages-with-css-media-queries.html

Or you could use something like AOP

https://apexofficeprint.com

And there are options in between

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=LS_DEMO:APEX5_PRINTING